# Google Cloud SQL 2nd generation : "certificates" is a keyword?

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-sql

I have loaded a database dump to a new Google Cloud SQL Instance 2nd generation (I was using 1st generation before) and I've seen that there is a new reserved word : "certificates".

Indeed, I have a column named "certificates" in a table and I'm forced to escape it with ``.

Obviously, EBean, the ORM I'm using with Play Framework, doesn't know this keyword and does not escape it.

I haven't found any information on this new keyword (on google or mysql official website).

I'm using Mysql 5.6 on both 1st generation and 2nd generation cloud sql instances and I don't have the problem on 1st generation.

Any option do desactivate this keyword ? What this keyword is made for ?

The simpliest workaround is of course to rename the column but I'm quite confused finding no informations about this keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. This was an unintentional side-effect of a mysql patch and will be fixed in a future release. If possible, I'd suggest renaming the column as a workaround if you can't wait until the new version is available.